# How to use client extension to enable RLS in Postgres using Prisma?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, prisma

As I explain below I have tried implementing client extension as suggested on [Github](https://github.com/prisma/prisma-client-extensions/tree/main/row-level-security).

Here is my migration.sql file where I define the policies for RLS:

```
-- Enable Row Level Security
ALTER TABLE "User" ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;
ALTER TABLE "Company" ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;

-- Force Row Level Security for table owners
ALTER TABLE "User" FORCE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;
ALTER TABLE "Company" FORCE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;

-- Create row security policies
CREATE POLICY tenant_isolation_policy ON "Company" USING ("id" = current_setting('app.current_company_id', TRUE)::uuid);
CREATE POL
```

Below is my schema.prisma file where I have defined only two models:

```
generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["clientExtensions"]
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Company {
  id    String @id @default(dbgenerated("gen_random_uuid()")) @db.Uuid
  name  String
  users User[]
}

model User {
  id        String  @id @default(dbgenerated("gen_random_uuid()")) @db.Uuid
  companyId String  @default(dbgenerated("(current_setting('app.current_company_id'::text))::uuid")) @db.Uuid
  email     String  @unique
  company   Company @relation(fields: [companyId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}
```

Below is my script.js file from which I am using different functions to validate if the RLS is working or not. To do so, I have created test data for both company and user tables, but I am unable to make companies or users unaccessible as it should be.

```
//Set a company_id as current_company_id for RLS Validation
const setUserId = await prisma.$executeRaw`SET app.current_company_id = 'id_of_a_company';`;
// Create a given company with a user
await prisma.company.create({
        data: {
          name: "Company 1",
          users: {
            create: {
              email: "user1@company1.com",
            },
          },
        },
      });
// Try to query users from Company 1 as a user who should have access
    const company1Users = await prisma.user.findMany({
        where: {
        company: {
            name: "Company 1",
        },
        },
    });
    // Try to query users from Company 2 as a user who should not have access
    const company2Users = await prisma.user.findMany({
        where: {
        company: {
            name: "Company 2",
        },
        },
    });
```

What Am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas as to what might be going wrong:

## First: Be sure to use extended PrismaClient

I don't see in your examples anywhere that shows you're actually extending the original PrismaClient with the relevant data stored in `current_settings` and then using that client to make queries.

For example, this is how you could set up the extended client to use the `current_settings`:

```js
const db = new PrismaClient()
const rlsDb = db.$extends(currentCompanyRlsExtension(session.company.id))

function currentCompanyRlsExtension(companyId) {
  return Prisma.defineExtension((prisma) =>
    prisma.$extends({
      query: {
        $allModels: {
          async $allOperations({ args, query }) {
            const [, result] = await prisma.$transaction([
              prisma.$executeRaw`SELECT set_config('app.current_company_id', ${companyId}, TRUE)`,
              query(args),
            ])
            return result
          },
        },
      },
    }),
  )
}
```

Then when you make queries to the database you need to use the extended client:

```js
const companyUsers = await rlsDb.user.findMany()
```

## Second: Be sure to use database user that cannot bypass RLS

Make sure your `DATABASE_URL` isn't using a database user that will always bypass RLS. From the [Postgresql v16](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html#:%7E:text=FORCE%20ROW%20LEVEL%20SECURITY.,using%20the%20DROP%20POLICY%20command.) docs:

> Superusers and roles with the `BYPASSRLS` attribute always bypass the row security system when accessing a table. Table owners normally bypass row security as well, though a table owner can choose to be subject to row security with ALTER TABLE ... FORCE ROW LEVEL SECURITY.